# How to add Gaussian noise to 3D data in matlab

Tags: matlab, 3d, point-cloud-library

During the experiment, you need to add different levels of Gaussian noise to the 3D data(point cloud or mesh), but only find the 2D Gaussian noise function. How can we add Gaussian noise to 3D data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it without any function, just using normally distributed random numbers (https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randn.html).
A gaussian noise can be defined as follows:

```
[M, N, P] = size(data);
noise = sqrt(sigma)*randn(M, N, P);
```

where sigma is the variance (power) of your noise, and M, N, P are the dimensions of the 3D data matrix.

Once you have correctly created your noise, simply add it to the data:

```
y = data + noise;
```

If you have an error, check the dimensions of the noise, they must be the same as the data.

Comment: You may want `randn(M, N, P)` MxN is 2D

Comment: To generalize, you can write `randn(size(data))`. That will work no matter how many dimensions there are in `data`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!